# Spark-only ProgressBar?

Tags: flash, flex4

In the [Flex4.5 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d8c.html) it says

> The ProgressBar control is part of the
>   MX component set. There is no Spark
>   equivalent.

This is a problem for apps that are Flex4-only (such as a mobile app).  What are people doing to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get you started with a progress bar: http://aaronhardy.com/flex/spark-progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't true for mobile flex projects.  Mobile projects require that you use components from the Spark namespace.  What have people been doing for progress bars on mobile?  I currently have one I made by stretching a single colored image across the bottom of the screen, it works but doesn't have the 3d look, feel, and animation of a real progress bar.